# IE8 & JS clone and prependTo does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, input-field

I'm using the Internet Explorer to execute an JS application.
Part of this application is to copy/clone an inputfield (including autocompletion functionality).

For that, I simply clone the input existing field:

```
field=$("#Searach_Field").clone().prependTo('#New_form');   //clone Element
field.attr('id','New_Search_Field');    //assign new ID to the input field.
```

This code works very well on firefox: the input field is cloned and also the auto completion works on the new input field.

But at the IE 8: there is no input field!
It looks like clone() or prependTo is not executed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

"#Serach_Field" is added to the page "READY" position of the document, while the clone() runs after loading the end (position:END) of the application/document.
That means: "#Serach_Field" does not exist at the time clone() is executing.

It looks like, this is not a problem for the firefox. Maybe the firefox is slower in processing the page, than the IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try to unchain the calls

```
field=$("#Serach_Field").clone();
field.attr('id','New_Search_Field');
$('#New_form').prepend(field);
```

There seem to have a typo in #Serach_Field.

Comment: thank you, for your answer. But there is no difference. Your version works well @ firefox but not at the IE8. :-(